# When is an explicit JOIN required in JPQL?

Tags: jpa

Consider the following JPA 2.0-compliant JPQL queries:

```
SELECT p
  FROM PostalAddress p
  JOIN p.constituent c
 WHERE c.id = :constituentId
 ORDER BY p.type.displayOrder
```

...and:

```
SELECT p
  FROM PostalAddress p
  JOIN p.constituent c
  JOIN p.type t
 WHERE c.id = :constituentId
 ORDER BY t.displayOrder
```

In both cases, `p.type` is a `@ManyToOne` relationship with another entity (`PostalAddressType`).

The difference in the two queries is that in the first one there is no explicit `JOIN` from `PostalAddress` to `PostalAddressType`.  It is implied, I guess, through the `p.type.displayOrder` snippet in the `WHERE` clause.  In the second, there is an explicit `JOIN`.

**Are these queries equivalent?**

Are they also equivalent to:

```
SELECT p
  FROM PostalAddress p
 WHERE p.constituent.id = :constituentId
 ORDER BY p.type.displayOrder
```

...?

It seems so.  In these cases, do the explicit `JOIN`s (between `PostalAddress` and `Constituent`, and between `PostalAddress` and `PostalAddressType`) help in any way (other than readability and explicitness)?

For completeness, I understand that a `JOIN` is always required if a path expression evaluates to a collection; I'm not (at the moment :-)) interested in that case.

Answer (score 3):

It's required each time you want a left join and not an inner join.

Comment: Thanks.  So all three queries above are equivalent?

Comment: It seems so, yes. The best way to check is to enable SQL logging and see what the generated SQL query is.

Comment: For a given provider, yes. Thanks.

Comment: Could I have a source for this statement please